# Responsive Nested Grid Layout

Tags: html, css, css-grid

In the following code, I have 4 inner grids within an outer grid layout. Both grids are responsive.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 10px;
  border: 2px red solid;
}

.grid > * > * {
  border: 2px blue dashed;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(35px, 1fr));
  grid-auto-rows: auto;
}

.grid > * > * > * {
  border: 1px green dashed;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>1</div>
      <div>1</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>2</div>
      <div>2</div>
      <div>2</div>
      <div>2</div>
      <div>2</div>
      <div>2</div>
      <div>2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>3</div>
      <div>3</div>
      <div>3</div>
      <div>3</div>
      <div>3</div>
      <div>3</div>
    </div>  
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>4</div>
      <div>4</div>
      <div>4</div>
      <div>4</div>
      <div>4</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

corresponding fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yg05zkx9/5/

Because I used auto-fill for the inner grids, spaces for empty tracks appear for the first grid, where the elements don't reach the last track because of lack of divs.

[image: image(4 empty tracks here)]

Is there a way to redistribute empty space from the empty tracks to all the inner grids?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just change this css and you're done with best possible way...
from

```
.grid > * > *{
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(35px, 1fr));
}
```

to

```
.grid > * > *{
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(35px, 1fr));
}
```

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 10px;
  border: 2px red solid;
}

.grid > * > * {
  border: 2px blue dashed;
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-rows: auto;
}

.grid > * > * > * {
  border: 1px green dashed;
}

.grid > * > * {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(35px, 1fr));
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
      <div>
        <div>
          <div>1</div>
          <div>1</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>2</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>3</div>
        </div>  
      </div>
      <div>
        <div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>4</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Try adding elements in first column containing 1

Comment: auto-fit only redistributes the space from the empty tracks to the grid elements in the same “inner” grid, is there a way to redistribute this space to the outer grid? Hence it is a nesting problem